# transformar dados de uma coluna de DataFrame em uma única string

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

tenho um DataFrame com uma coluna que possui diferentes textos em cada linha e pretendo unir todas as linhas em uma única string, é possível?

a ideia é transformar todas as frases da coluna em um só texto e em seguida fazer análises com nltk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o **to_string**

```
df['Coluna'].to_string()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

palavras = ['ola','como','vai','você?']
dados = pd.DataFrame({'Texto': palavras})
dados
```

Dados

```
    Texto
0   olá
1   como
2   vai
3   você?
```

Transformando em string

```
dados['Texto'].to_string(index=False).strip().replace('\n','')
```

Saída

```
'olá  como   vai você?'
```

Comment: mas nesse caso eu vou alterar o tipo da coluna, o que quero fazer é transformar todas as linhas da coluna em uma só string.

Comment: @Victor, bom dia! Esse comando transforma as linhas da coluna em uma string única. Abraço!

Comment: boa, obrigado! quando eu testei esse método a string era formada somente com o que estava visível no DataFrame, então se o texto fosse grande e na visualização do DataFrame ficasse '...', a string levaria a frase cortada com as reticências. usei o pd.set_option('max_colwidth', False) pra resolver.